# How to use these pronouns?

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

Please check out these examples! And kindly tell me about their sense. Are they grammatically right?
I'm just learning grammar principals

Ours/Our

> The house is perpetual since last year, but we could change its look, after all, it is going to become ours. Our journey was exceptional.

Its/It

> It’s a very cool weather, and how could someone at some other place imagine its curiosity. She doesn’t like it when you are so quiet.

Your/Yours

> Your grace is utmostly remarkable. All of a sudden, when you took the charge, that was yours grace, admiring everyone.

Comment: You might want to try and simplify your sentences rather than post such complicated examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that we use possessive determiners (your, our, its) **before a noun**, while possessive pronouns (yours, ours, its) are used **in place of a noun**. Note that for personal pronoun "it" both possessive determiner and possessive pronoun forms are identical - "its".

According to this, sentences with our/ours seem to be correct. Also sentences with it/its look good. However in sentence "All of a sudden, when you took the charge, that was yours grace, admiring everyone" possessive pronoun "yours" is not used correctly. Instead you can say "that was your grace" or "that was grace of yours", and that would be correct.

There is also second grammar error in this sentence as I believe you didn't mean that "grace was admiring everyone", but rather that "grace was admired by everyone".

Comment: The sentence should be, I guess: All of a sudden, when you took the charge, that was grace of yours, admired by everyone.

Comment: Could we use 'It' and 'Its', alternatively?